# Connecting Android Studio with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, android-studio

Is there anyway to connect Android studio with MongoDB without using mlabs and API

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! At this point, your question is too vague. Please update it to add relevant details that will help us define your problem: what have you tried, the errors you are seeing, the steps you took to get there, etc.

Comment: It's not possible to connect **Android Studio** [IDE] with MongoDB. You need [edit] the question and post [mcve] here as CydrickT suggested.